# Call scripts in directories relative to main script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Currently, I am working with a shell script and make a system where I write a shell script say `main.sh` and the same directory there is a directory containing other shell scripts. The structure is:

```
root_directory
|___scripts
|   |___script1.sh
|   |___script2.sh
|   |___script3.sh
|
|___main.sh
```

Now the `main.sh` is the base file. In this `main.sh` I call the scripts like

```
bash ./scripts/script1.sh
bash ./scripts/script2.sh
```

and so on.
Everything works fine when I run the `main.sh` file from `root_directory` directory. But I want to install the total system globally as I can run the `main.sh` file from anywhere and it can find the `scripts` subfolder.

If any query then feel free to comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get a script file’s directory by running

```
echo "${0%/*}"  # or
dirname "$0"
```

in the script, so just change the lines to

```
bash "${0%/*}/scripts/script1.sh"          # or respectively
bash "$(dirname "$0")/scripts/script1.sh"
```

or define a variable, e.g.

```
script_dir="${0%/*}/scripts"          # or respectively
script_dir="$(dirname "$0")/scripts"
```

and use that for the paths:

```
bash "$script_dir"/script1.sh
```

In a script, `$0` holds the script file’s path in its absolute or relative form depending on how you called it. `dirname` just extracts the directory name, which is the path of `root_directory` in your case. The same thing can be done with [`bash` Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe): `${0%/*}` simply deletes everything from the last slash `/`, which is the filename. With both ways the path remains an absolute or relative path.

I found the `dirname` solution on [Get path of current script when executed through a symlink • U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17500/246819), please upvote this answer (as well ;) if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

i don't usually answer questions on this platform so please correct me if i step on anyone's toes.

If i understand your question correctly, you want `main.sh` to run globally when you call the bash file on the terminal.

- 1st step check if the name `main` has been used by any other program in my os.
  run `~$ which <file name>` which in your case refers to main
  if no result is found, that means the identifier is free to use
- 2nd step open the bash file and add shebang on top `#!/bin/bash` this is what i use mostly. Save the file and exit
- 3rd move the bash file to `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` this will require a root access.
- 4th set the bash file to executable by running this command `chmod +x <file-name>` this will allow any user to run that particular script. if you want to restrict who has access use this command instead `chmod u+x <file-name>`

After that you can run the bash file anywhere. Here is a good [resource](https://www.howtogeek.com/261591/how-to-create-and-run-bash-shell-scripts-on-windows-10/)

Comment: You didn't understand the question. It is not about running the main script, but about calling companion scripts from it, when these scripts in a fixed location relative to the main.